# Trying to set an image as the background and keep it from getting the bottom cut off when scrolling while using MUI component library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to this using MUI. I know that by switching the the main Box to a div and then setting the position as realative solves this but I want to do it the MUI way because I am trying to learn how to get better with this component library.Please see my code below:

```
return (

    <Box 
        sx={{height:'100vh', position:"relative"}}
    
    >
        <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full z-0">
            <img
            className="w-full h-full object-cover"
            src="https://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/macos-high-sierra-default-wallpaper-fall-mountain-scene-1.jpg"
            alt="/"
            />
            <div className="bg-black/40 absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full">

            </div>
        </div>
        <Navbar className="relative w-full"
         
        />

        <Box
            width="100%"
            
            padding="2rem 6%"
            display={isNonMobileScreens ? "flex" : "block"}
            gap="0.5rem"
            justifyContent="space-between"
            
        >
            <Box flexBasis={isNonMobileScreens ? "26%" : undefined}
              padding={isNonMobileScreens ? "1.5rem 1.5rem 0.75rem 1.5rem" : undefined}
              className="z-10"
              
            >

             <RandomHobbyWidget/>
            </Box>
            <Box
                flexBasis={isNonMobileScreens ? "50%" : undefined}
                mt={isNonMobileScreens ? undefined : "2rem"}
                padding={isNonMobileScreens ? "1.5rem 1.5rem 0.75rem 1.5rem" : undefined}
                className="z-10"
                
                
            >
                <MyPostWidget picturePath={picturePath} />
                <PostsWidget userId={_id} />
            
            </Box>

            <Box
                flexBasis={isNonMobileScreens ? "26%" : undefined}
                padding={isNonMobileScreens ? "1.5rem 1.5rem 0.75rem 1.5rem" : undefined}
            >
                <WeatherWidget/>

                
            </Box>
        
        </Box>

       
    </Box>

);
```

};